# PHP Facebook app posting to others walls

Tags: php, facebook

This is a pretty general question, and if this type if questions is incorrect for me to post, I will delete it, and im sorry in advance.

Can anyone tell me the general hurdles I would need to overcome to create a facebook app that can post to someone else's wall?

Im a PHP developer, and dont need any specifics on code, but a overview of whats necessary to post something on someone elses wall programatically.

More to the point, whats involved in getting permission to post to someone's wall?

A link to a resource would be great.. Ive looked, and found things close on facebook itself, but nothing that spells out how to get permission to post to someone else.

ALSO

Can anyone help me verify that longest access token a facebook app can receive to post to someone elses wall is 60 days?

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

"long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about 60 days"

The term usually has me for a loop here because I cant find any more info.

If anyone might know, is it possible to create a facebook app that, once someone gives permission, could post to that persons wall until they 'stop' using the app?

Comment: For reasons I understand, but this is for a product my company is producing, the ability to post to a facebook users wall compliments this product very well.

Comment: Ah, ok, so this is different. In this case, since it is complimenting a companies product it is obviously ok to deal with the devil. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished via [the feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2). It was available in the Graph API prior to February 2013 but that option is no longer available.

The `to` parameter is what you're looking for. Note the highlighted bit as it's pretty critical:

> The ID of the profile that this story will be published to. If this is unspecified, it defaults to the value of from. **The ID must be a friend who also uses your app.**

Comment: The point of the app would be to get permission to post upcoming reminders for our service to the facebook wall of users. Should I choose facebook canvis app, or website app?

Comment: @Jason You should read the documentation and decide. Their differences don't seem very relevant to the information in this question.

Comment: Posting upcoming reminders on peoples walls are not ok according to Facebook Platform Policy

Comment: WizKid, where in that long document do you see the language that makes you say that? I dont see it.